# query of sqlite3 with python using '?'

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a table of three columns`id,word,essay`.I want to do a query using (`?`). The sql sentence is `sql1 = "select id,? from training_data"`. My code is below:

```
def dbConnect(db_name,sql,flag):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if (flag == "danci"):
        itm = 'word'
    elif flag == "wenzhang":
        itm = 'essay'
    n = cursor.execute(sql,(itm,))
    res1 = cursor.fetchall()
    return res1
```

However, when I `print dbConnect("data.db",sql1,"danci")`
The result I obtained is `[(1,'word'),(2,'word'),(3,'word')...].`What I really want to get is `[(1,'the content of word column'),(2,'the content of word column')...]`. What should I do ? Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use placeholders for identifiers -- only for literal values.

I don't know what to suggest in this case, as your function takes a database nasme, an SQL string, and a flag to say how to modify that string. I think it would be better to pass just the first two, and write something like

```
sql = {
    "danci":    "SELECT id, word  FROM training_data",
    "wenzhang": "SELECT id, essay FROM training_data",
}
```

and then call it with one of

```
dbConnect("data.db", sql['danci'])
```

or

```
dbConnect("data.db", sql['wenzhang'])
```

But a lot depends on why you are asking `dbConnect` to decide on the columns to fetch based on a string passed in from outside; it's an unusual design.

---

**Update - SQL Injection**

The problems with [*SQL injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [tainted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking) [data](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#SECURITY-MECHANISMS-AND-CONCERNS) is well documented, but here is a summary.

The principle is that, in theory, a programmer can write safe and secure programs as long as all the sources of data are under his control. As soon as they use any information from outside the program without checking its integrity, security is under threat.

Such information ranges from the obvious -- the parameters passed on the command line -- to the obscure -- if the `PATH` environment variable is modifiable then someone could induce a program to execute a completely different file from the intended one.

Perl provides direct help to avoid such situations with [Taint Checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking), but *SQL Injection* is the open door that is relevant here.

Suppose you take the value for a database column from an unverfied external source, and that value appears in your program as `$val`. Then, if you write

```
my $sql = "INSERT INTO logs (date) VALUES ('$val')";
$dbh->do($sql);
```

then it looks like it's going to be okay. For instance, if `$val` is set to `2014-10-27` then `$sql` becomes

```
INSERT INTO logs (date) VALUES ('2014-10-27')
```

and everything's fine. But now suppose that our data is being provided by someone less than scrupulous or downright malicious, and your `$val`, having originated elsewhere, contains this

```
2014-10-27'); DROP TABLE logs; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM security WHERE name != '
```

Now it doesn't look so good. `$sql` is set to this (with added newlines)

```
INSERT INTO logs (date) VALUES ('2014-10-27');
DROP TABLE logs;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM security WHERE name != '')
```

which adds an entry to the `logs` table as before, end then goes ahead and drops the entire `logs` table and counts the number of records in the `security` table. That isn't what we had in mind at all, and something we must guard against.

The immediate solution is to use *placeholders* `?` in a *prepared* statement, and later passing the actual values in a call to `execute`. This not only speeds things up, because the SQL statement can be prepared (compiled) just once, but protects the database from malicious data by *quoting* every supplied value appropriately for the data type, and *escaping* any embedded quotes so that it is impossible to close one statement and another open another.

This whole concept was humourised in [*Randall Munroe's* excellent XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I would stress more the reasoning behind not simply replacing the word (sql-injection). Other than that, good answer.

Comment: @deets: Yes, in general, however, there's not really a SQL injection vulnerability here because the column name is embedded in the code. In this specific case it is safe to use string formatting to build the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You mean I can't use '?' for column name?

Comment: @wanglan8498: Yes, I mean exactly that. As you've seen, if you use a placeholder then it replaces it with the *string value* of the bound variable rather than a column name.

Comment: @Borodin *I* know this, *you* know this, and your code isn't vulnerable - the OP though doesn't know I presume, thus I tend to emphasise this whenever I give answers that essentially boil down to modifying queries dependent on user-input.

Comment: @deets: Please supplement my solution if you feel that it's appropriate

Comment: @deets: If you could,please explain more the detail behind.Because I want to learn more and know exactly.

Comment: @deets: The concept of Stack Overflow is that you can edit any post if you think it can be improved. The idea is not to badger the author to make the changes that you want.

Comment: @wanglan8498: I have added to my answer to explain SQL injection. `@deets` is clearly about barracking people to do as he wishes rather than providing information himself.

Comment: @Borodin I'm sorry if I upset you, that wasn't my intention. I wouldn't have edited your post at all, if you hadn't asked me to "supplement your solution". This I interpreted as "edit it", which apparently wasn't what you wanted. I'm happy to admit that I still struggle somewhat with the workings of providing good answers & distinguishing between commenting and answering here at stackoverflow. So - what *should* I have done, if I felt that your answer provided a good solution, but lacked the elaboration about sql injection? Reproduce it + the SQL injection info?

Comment: @deets: I'm not upset at all. Maybe a little angry, but I may have misunderstood your intention, which is still unclear. But still your comment confuses me. You *didn't* edit my solution, and that is exactly what I would expect you to do. You are always welcome to do that, as long as you don't mind if I roll back your changes! And the same applies to any other post that you see on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn't edit it? I pressed the edit-button, added a paragraph to the end explaining escaping of values, dangers of sql-injection & a small example with the "drop table" stuff and submitted it. It then said something about "awaiting peer review". what appeared on your side of things?

Comment: @deets: Exactly the same as on your side. There are three versions in total, all authored by me. If you had submitted a change then I would have to roll it back to reject it, and that would be an additional entry in the history

Comment: Then I'm totally confused about what happened. Ok, one thing that happened is that I misread your comment above "The concept of Stack Overflow is..." and interpreted the "is" as "isn't" - probably because of you being angry at me for what I thought was editing your post, so I kinda assumed that was wrong in general. But I swear to the flying spaghetti-monster, I did exactly what I just described - attempting to augment your post by editing. In this world of AJAX-based updates and whatnot, I don't have a browser-history to look through & track back what went wrong where. So, again, apologies.

Comment: @deets: There's no need for your apologies - we simply misunderstood one other with the help of the web site. I would have liked to see what you wrote. I do think it's possible that, if two people hit `Submit` at the same time, only one of the updates will be entered while the other is lost silently, but there's no way to hide a legitimate update once it has been posted